# Problem with unsollicited change of value for pytest fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I'm new to pytest and I can't solve an annoying problem.
I want to have a fixture with base test values from a dataclass. And for certain test functions, I want to to modify some of these values locally to test some specificities. But I want to keep the base values unaltered for the next test functions !

Here's my code:

```
import pytest
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Def_Input:
    var1 = 3
    var2 = 4
    
@pytest.fixture
def def_inp():
    def_inp = Def_Input()
    return def_inp

def test_1(def_inp):
    temp = def_inp
    temp.var1 = 5
    assert def_inp.var1 == 3
    assert temp.var1 + temp.var2 == 9
```

The 2nd assert is not a problem, but the first one is. I get an AssertionError saying def_inp.var1 = 5 when I didn't modify def_inp, I used a temporary variable...

Would you have any ideas at to solve this?

Edit:
@Steven97102 this does work for the example I gave, but I work on a slightly more complex function. In the dataclass, I create objects from external classes. It's something like this:

```
import pytest
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Tab:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

@dataclass
class Def_Input:
    var1 = 3
    var2 = 4
    name = 'paul'
    tab = Tab(name)
    
@pytest.fixture
def def_inp():
    def_inp = Def_Input()
    return def_inp

def test_1(def_inp):
    temp = dataclasses.replace(def_inp)
    temp.var1 = 5
    temp.tab.name = 'john'
    assert def_inp.tab.name == 'paul'
    assert def_inp.var1 == 3
    assert temp.var1 + temp.var2 == 9
```

Would you know I could get the first assert to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python passes class instances using the reference model. This means that `temp = def_inp` simply creates a variable `temp` that points to the same object as `def_inp`. To avoid modifying the existing instance, you will have to create a new instance of it.

Here's a solution that makes a deep copy of `def_inp`:

```py
import pytest
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Def_Input:
    var1 = 3
    var2 = 4
    
@pytest.fixture
def def_inp():
    def_inp = Def_Input()
    return def_inp

def test_1(def_inp):

    # make a deep copy of "def_inp"
    temp = dataclasses.replace(def_inp)

    temp.var1 = 5
    assert def_inp.var1 == 3
    assert temp.var1 + temp.var2 == 9
```

Comment: oh thanks! that should do it for me!